# Breaking the value in rows

Tags: sql, oracle

```
:20201:RBIPTRN256619568|:57561:RBIP0NEFTSC|:55691:BCBM0000999|:35351:1730|:51801:10|:41101:103470.00|:41102:INR|
:2020_1:hdgdydhdhd|:2006_1:hdjddkddl|:3380_1:11-11-2019|:3375_1:11-11-2019|:40381_1:200.00|:40382_1:INR|:6091_1:gdgdjdjdj|:6305_1:10|:6310_1:|:6021_1:156464646|:6061_1:hsbsjskss|:6081_1:hsbshsksks hssb|:5569_1:bsbshshs|:5756_1:SRCB0000014|:55651_1:hsbshsjsks|:55652_1:hsbsbsbns|:6346_1:R09|:6366_1:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|
:2020_2:Tjsksls;|:2006_2:jnsllls|:3380_2:11-11-2019|:3375_2:11-11-2019|:40381_2:500.00|:40382_2:INR|:6091_2:hssbskjs|:6305_2:10|:6310_2:|:6021_2:014200100024493|:6061_2:001510100133438B|:6081_2:iusnsms|:5569_2:BCBM0000001|:5756_2:SRCB0000014|:55651_2:usnns|:55652_2:llslsl|:6346_2:R09|:6366_2:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|
```

**it is the value of a single column.**

So my requiremnt is,
I want my output as

```
:20201:RBIPTRN256619568|:57561:RBIP0NEFTSC|:55691:BCBM0000999|:35351:1730|:51801:10|:41101:103470.00|:41102:INR|
:2020_1:hdgdydhdhd|:2006_1:hdjddkddl|:3380_1:11-11-2019|:3375_1:11-11-2019|:40381_1:200.00|:40382_1:INR|:6091_1:gdgdjdjdj|:6305_1:10|:6310_1:|:6021_1:156464646|:6061_1:hsbsjskss|:6081_1:hsbshsksks hssb|:5569_1:bsbshshs|:5756_1:SRCB0000014|:55651_1:hsbshsjsks|:55652_1:hsbsbsbns|:6346_1:R09|:6366_1:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|
```

in one row
and

```
:2020_2:Tjsksls;|:2006_2:jnsllls|:3380_2:11-11-2019|:3375_2:11-11-2019|:40381_2:500.00|:40382_2:INR|:6091_2:hssbskjs|:6305_2:10|:6310_2:|:6021_2:014200100024493|:6061_2:001510100133438B|:6081_2:iusnsms|:5569_2:BCBM0000001|:5756_2:SRCB0000014|:55651_2:usnns|:55652_2:llslsl|:6346_2:R09|:6366_2:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|
```

in another row

Comment: Simplify the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the second instance of a line feed character and get the sub-strings before and after:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT ':20201:RBIPTRN256619568|:57561:RBIP0NEFTSC|:55691:BCBM0000999|:35351:1730|:51801:10|:41101:103470.00|:41102:INR|
:2020_1:hdgdydhdhd|:2006_1:hdjddkddl|:3380_1:11-11-2019|:3375_1:11-11-2019|:40381_1:200.00|:40382_1:INR|:6091_1:gdgdjdjdj|:6305_1:10|:6310_1:|:6021_1:156464646|:6061_1:hsbsjskss|:6081_1:hsbshsksks hssb|:5569_1:bsbshshs|:5756_1:SRCB0000014|:55651_1:hsbshsjsks|:55652_1:hsbsbsbns|:6346_1:R09|:6366_1:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|
:2020_2:Tjsksls;|:2006_2:jnsllls|:3380_2:11-11-2019|:3375_2:11-11-2019|:40381_2:500.00|:40382_2:INR|:6091_2:hssbskjs|:6305_2:10|:6310_2:|:6021_2:014200100024493|:6061_2:001510100133438B|:6081_2:iusnsms|:5569_2:BCBM0000001|:5756_2:SRCB0000014|:55651_2:usnns|:55652_2:llslsl|:6346_2:R09|:6366_2:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR( value, 1, second_line_break - 1 ) AS column1,
       SUBSTR( value, second_line_break + 1 ) AS column2
FROM   (
  SELECT value,
         INSTR( value, CHR(10), 1, 2 ) AS second_line_break
  FROM   test_data
);
```

**Output**:

> ```
> COLUMN1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             | COLUMN2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
> :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> :20201:RBIPTRN256619568|:57561:RBIP0NEFTSC|:55691:BCBM0000999|:35351:1730|:51801:10|:41101:103470.00|:41102:INR|<br>:2020_1:hdgdydhdhd|:2006_1:hdjddkddl|:3380_1:11-11-2019|:3375_1:11-11-2019|:40381_1:200.00|:40382_1:INR|:6091_1:gdgdjdjdj|:6305_1:10|:6310_1:|:6021_1:156464646|:6061_1:hsbsjskss|:6081_1:hsbshsksks hssb|:5569_1:bsbshshs|:5756_1:SRCB0000014|:55651_1:hsbshsjsks|:55652_1:hsbsbsbns|:6346_1:R09|:6366_1:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED| | :2020_2:Tjsksls;|:2006_2:jnsllls|:3380_2:11-11-2019|:3375_2:11-11-2019|:40381_2:500.00|:40382_2:INR|:6091_2:hssbskjs|:6305_2:10|:6310_2:|:6021_2:014200100024493|:6061_2:001510100133438B|:6081_2:iusnsms|:5569_2:BCBM0000001|:5756_2:SRCB0000014|:55651_2:usnns|:55652_2:llslsl|:6346_2:R09|:6366_2:OPERATIONS SUSPENDED|
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a65861475ea02f587eb38c93067b6b59)*

Comment: Sorry to say, but the above query didn't help

Comment: @PiyushBaria "didn't help" is not a constructive statement; please try to expand on "why" it didn't help or what the problems still are. You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58816402/edit) to include additional details and/or test cases or if the problem is significantly different then ask a new question with a detailed problem description.

Comment: If not in column can you help with fetching the same record in 2 different rows.

Comment: @PiyushBaria `UNPIVOT` the columns? [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=22ea46387e036957c011bc1e8423c0cc)

Answer (score 0):

to cut a text use `SUBSTR`

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(':20201:RBIPTRN256619568|',1,16) as FirstSTRING 
SUBSTR(':20201:RBIPTRN256619568|',17,24) as SecondSTRING
from dual
```

result:

```
  FirstSTRING         SecondSTRING
:20201:RBIPTRN25        6619568|
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: @PiyushBaria `STRING(string or text,m,n)` command allows you to cut a string from a character (m) to character (n). e.g. string is (abcdefg). you can try `SELECT SUBSTR('abcdefg',1,5) as STRING from dual` it will result as (**abcde**). start from 1st letter to 5th

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. But my requirement is lets after firing your query I am getting output as 'abcde' but I want it as 'abc' in one row and 'de' in another row. Hope you got it now.

Comment: I want my output in 2 different rows.

Comment: sorry, I thought you got the answer from @MT0 answer as you accepted his answer. anyway, check my edited query, you can add as many columns as you like. just put your full text.